# Word for incidents you think are still happening but aren’t

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word, that is suitable for the following scenario in bold:

> For two years I used to go to the same restaurant with my best friend. Then I moved somewhere else. A  year passed, and I came back to the same restaurant and ordered a dish. **Suddenly, someone entered, and immediately I thought it was my old friend.** However, in reality it was someone else.
>   <sub><sup>passage copy-edited</sup></sub>

So, what do we call a situation when we start thinking that the past is repeating but in reality, it's not. Like having hallucination that you are with your friend, but in reality he is not here. He's coming in your mind, because you spent a long time with him.

Comment: You could say you had a reverie about the past experience you've had at the hotel...

Comment: Thank you, this is the sentence I was looking for. 

Is there any single word to express this whole? If not, I am good with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't believe *reverie* fits.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  As per the definition of reverie: a state of being pleasantly lost in one's thoughts; a daydream. The sentence fits not the word(reverie), because I lost in such a way, that I feels his presence near to me. That's why I requested for a particular word.

Comment: Well, daydreaming is not exactly the same as thinking the past is repeating, or that you are reliving a past experience. But if you're happy with that expression then I'd suggest that @AndySemyonov post his suggestion, so you can accept the answer.  :)

Comment: Yes, i second you on that, the daydreaming is not exactly the same as repeating past. But you always prefer to dream of the things that you like, or good incidents happened at particular place. And it is a good memories that having a lunch with my friend, so I can consider this. But I need to mention about the  **hotel** in my sentence.

Comment: From your description, you simply **mistook** the person entering the restaurant for your friend. It is hardly a hallucinatory experience. After all, it was *you* who moved away. He stayed. Now you are back again, sitting in the very restaurant you both visited often. That it could be your friend is entirely plausible.  If you got a strong memory of a particular time in the restaurant, triggered by this incident, maybe you want a word about the nature of memory?

Comment: @SarvsavSharma The way this is punctuated now, "Suddenly, someone __entered and in my mind__, I thought that its my friend," it's very ambiguous, as though he entered your mind. Also, your tenses are totally mixed/messed up, as in "I come back to same restaurant and ordered."

Comment: @MariusHancu Yes, it is horrible. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be referring to a [deja vu](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0%20vu):

> - the feeling that you have already experienced something that is actually happening for the first time
> - something that has happened many times before : something that is very familiar

Comment: For the first part deja vu seems correct, but when I visit the place again after a long time, the things are actually not happening (my friend actually didn't visit the place), they are just my hallucinations (it just in my mind, that he is here). I am looking the word for second part.

Comment: @SarvsavSharma - Your scenario is well within the normal coloquial definition of "deja vu".

Comment: @Sarvsav, I would be careful with your use of "hallucination" here. As I understand it, a hallucination is something not immediately recognised as such, but mistaken for objective reality. If you hallucinated that your old college professor had entered the restaurant, you might go up to him and ask how he was doing. Whereupon the staff might ask you why you are talking to the umbrella stand. You insist that the umbrella stand is your prof, and they take you away.

Comment: @HotLicks: I believe that the scenario described in the question is *the exact opposite* of the normal colloquial definition of “déjà vu”. In the normal colloquial definition of “déjà vu”, the subject perceives the current situation accurately, and involuntarily/unconsciously imagines (fabricates) a past event that corresponds to the current situation. In the OP’s scenario, he recalls the past accurately, and involuntarily/unconsciously imagines (fabricates) a current event that resembles and resonates with the past.

Comment: @Scott - Well there's always *jamais vu*.

Comment: @HotLicks: If you believe that that's relevant to this question, why don't you post it as an answer? I believe that it doesn't really work — it's opposite in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest ***flashback:***

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flashback):
>
>   a past incident recurring vividly in the mind
>   Example: He’s having
>   *flashbacks*
>   of his days in the war.
>
> [the Oxford dictionary (American English)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flashback):
>
>   A sudden and disturbing vivid memory of an event in the past, typically as the result of psychological trauma or taking LSD.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_(psychology)):
>
>   A
>   **flashback**
>   , or
>   **involuntary recurrent memory**
>   ,
>     is a psychological phenomenon in which an individual has a sudden,
>     usually powerful, re-experiencing of a past experience
>     or elements of a past experience. 
>     These experiences can be happy, sad, exciting,
>     or any other emotion one can consider. 
>     The term is used particularly when the memory is recalled involuntarily,
>     and/or when it is so intense that the person “relives” the experience,
>     unable to fully recognize it as memory
>     and not something that is happening in “real time”.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing what is known as *confabulation*, aka the Mandela Effect.

> *Psychiatry.* the replacement of a gap in a person's memory by a falsification that he or she believes to be true. ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/confabulation))

This is done without the conscious intention to deceive.